# How can I add columns to a Matrix in a BIDS Report project?

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, bids, rdl

When I add a Matrix to the Layout page in the BIDS designer, it creates two columns. I need more. I would expect the Matrix control to have a "ColumnCount" property, but it doesn't.

My next expectation would be that the Matrix would provide a context-sensitive menu allowing me to insert columns. It doesn't. If I click the matrix,  a textbox gets selected instead. Although I can get to the matrix by pressing the "Esc" key to make the Matrix the selected control, there still is no likely option in the context menu or on its properties page.

Adding columns has got to be one of the most common things to do - how is it done?

Trying to make sense of the .rdl file doesn't help me much, either; there seems to be no rhyme or reason to the way things are organized in it. On the design surface, I have a Matrix with two columns and two rows. Row 1 contains two labels in Textboxes. Row 2 contains textboxes with field expressions assigned to their Value property. Yet the .rdl (xml) file has one of the labels ("WEEK 1 USAGE") in a ColumnGroupings.ColumnGrouping.DynamicColumns.ReportItems section, and the other ("PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION") in a Corner.ReportItems section.

As to the data, one (PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION.Value) is in a RowGroupings.RowGrouping.DynamicRows.ReportItems section, and the other (WEEK1USAGE.Value) in a MatrixRows.MatrixRow.MatrixCells.MatrixCell.ReportItems section.

To prove that I haven't gone craz[ier,y], here's the rdl/xml for the matrix in question (with the appearance of the label/data elements rearranged to be a little more logical than their actual order of appearance, and with some superfluous things (ZOrder, etc.) elided):

```
<Matrix Name="matrix1">

  <MatrixColumns>
    <MatrixColumn>
      <Width>2.375in</Width>
    </MatrixColumn>
  </MatrixColumns>

  // "PLATYPUS DESCRIPTION" label
  <Corner>
    <ReportItems>
      <Textbox Name="textbox2">
        <rd:DefaultName>textbox2</rd:DefaultName>
        <Style>
          <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
          <FontWeight>700</FontWeight>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
        <ZIndex>3</ZIndex>
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <Value>PLATYPUS DESCRIPTION</Value>
      </Textbox>
    </ReportItems>
  </Corner>

  // PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION data
  <RowGroupings>
    <RowGrouping>
      <Width>2.75in</Width>
      <DynamicRows>
        <Grouping Name="matrix1_RowGroup1">
          <GroupExpressions>
            <GroupExpression />
          </GroupExpressions>
        </Grouping>
        <ReportItems>
          <Textbox Name="textboxDescription">
            <Style>
              <FontSize>11pt</FontSize>
              <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
              <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
              <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
              <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
            </Style>
            <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
            <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
            <Value>=Fields!PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION.Value</Value>
          </Textbox>
        </ReportItems>
      </DynamicRows>
    </RowGrouping>
  </RowGroupings>

  // "WEEK 1 USAGE" label
  <ColumnGroupings>
    <ColumnGrouping>
      <Height>0.25in</Height>
      <DynamicColumns>
        <Grouping Name="matrix1_ColumnGroup1">
          <GroupExpressions>
            <GroupExpression />
          </GroupExpressions>
        </Grouping>
        <ReportItems>
          <Textbox Name="textbox3">
            <rd:DefaultName>textbox3</rd:DefaultName>
            <Style>
              <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
              <FontWeight>700</FontWeight>
              <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
              <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
              <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
              <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
            </Style>
            <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
            <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
            <Value>WEEK 1 USAGE</Value>
          </Textbox>
        </ReportItems>
      </DynamicColumns>
    </ColumnGrouping>
  </ColumnGroupings>

  // WEEK1USAGE data
  <MatrixRows>
    <MatrixRow>
      <Height>0.25in</Height>
      <MatrixCells>
        <MatrixCell>
          <ReportItems>
            <Textbox Name="textboxWeek1Usage">
              <Style>
                <FontSize>11pt</FontSize>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
              </Style>
              <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
              <Value>=Fields!WEEK1USAGE.Value</Value>
            </Textbox>
          </ReportItems>
        </MatrixCell>
      </MatrixCells>
    </MatrixRow>
  </MatrixRows>
  <Height>0.5in</Height>
  <Left>0.25in</Left>
</Matrix>
```

### UPDATE

And here is the actual excerpt of the entire "matrix1" section of the rdl/xml file:

```
  <Matrix Name="matrix1">
    <MatrixColumns>
      <MatrixColumn>
        <Width>2.375in</Width>
      </MatrixColumn>
    </MatrixColumns>
    <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
    <DataSetName>PriceVarianceSP</DataSetName>
    <RowGroupings>
      <RowGrouping>
        <Width>2.75in</Width>
        <DynamicRows>
          <Grouping Name="matrix1_RowGroup1">
            <GroupExpressions>
              <GroupExpression />
            </GroupExpressions>
          </Grouping>
          <ReportItems>
            <Textbox Name="textboxDescription">
              <Style>
                <FontSize>11pt</FontSize>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
              </Style>
              <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
              <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
              <Value>=Fields!PROACTDESCRIPTION.Value</Value>
            </Textbox>
          </ReportItems>
        </DynamicRows>
      </RowGrouping>
    </RowGroupings>
    <Top>0.5in</Top>
    <ColumnGroupings>
      <ColumnGrouping>
        <Height>0.25in</Height>
        <DynamicColumns>
          <Grouping Name="matrix1_ColumnGroup1">
            <GroupExpressions>
              <GroupExpression />
            </GroupExpressions>
          </Grouping>
          <ReportItems>
            <Textbox Name="textbox3">
              <rd:DefaultName>textbox3</rd:DefaultName>
              <Style>
                <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
                <FontWeight>700</FontWeight>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
              </Style>
              <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
              <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
              <Value>WEEK 1 USAGE</Value>
            </Textbox>
          </ReportItems>
        </DynamicColumns>
      </ColumnGrouping>
    </ColumnGroupings>
    <Width>5.125in</Width>
    <Corner>
      <ReportItems>
        <Textbox Name="textbox2">
          <rd:DefaultName>textbox2</rd:DefaultName>
          <Style>
            <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
            <FontWeight>700</FontWeight>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
          <ZIndex>3</ZIndex>
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <Value>DESCRIPTION</Value>
        </Textbox>
      </ReportItems>
    </Corner>
    <MatrixRows>
      <MatrixRow>
        <Height>0.25in</Height>
        <MatrixCells>
          <MatrixCell>
            <ReportItems>
              <Textbox Name="textboxWeek1Usage">
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>11pt</FontSize>
                  <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                  <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                  <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                  <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <Value>=Fields!WEEK1USAGE.Value</Value>
              </Textbox>
            </ReportItems>
          </MatrixCell>
        </MatrixCells>
      </MatrixRow>
    </MatrixRows>
    <Height>0.5in</Height>
    <Left>0.25in</Left>
  </Matrix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns are added dynamically depending on your column group expression. For example, let's say you want to display the usage data on each day of the month (and assume the `DateUsed` has no time component) then your matrix has only one column with a column group expression being the date used `=Fields!DateUsed.Value` and the "Detail" cell sums the usage on that day `=Sum(Fields!Usage.Value)`.

So your matrix looks very simple:

```
                           |  =Fields!DateUsed.Value
---------------------------+-----------------------------
=Fields!Description.Value  | =Sum(Fields!Usage.Value)
```

That's all there is to it.

The matrix then adds as many columns as there are dates in your data when you run the report.

Comment: Similar to my other question/your other answer, I don't want to perform any summation here (so I apparently don't really want a Matrix); I just want to display the data I'm getting back from the dataset / Stored Procedure.

Comment: Okay, then you don't want a matrix - matrices are all about automating the summing of data in a pivot table type of format - grouping and expanding horizontally as well as vertically. It sounds like you just want a plain old table.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the Table control, too, and also with it I saw no way to add columns. A "ColumnCount" property would be nice, as would a Property Editor to add field values to the columns. SSRS is starting to give me the fantods, and I have the uneasy feeling that it is the long-lost cousin of SharePoint.

Comment: To add a column, click on the table anywhere, then right-click the column handle (grey button-looking thing at the top) hover over Insert Column then click either Left or Right. Easy when you know how (unlike SharePoint which remains a beast regardless). Stick with SSRS - it is an amazingly powerful, flexible and extensible reporting tool once you are up to speed.

Comment: I was finally able to get back to this today; yes, the Table control is not bad, once I grokked it with your help: Use the first row for the label you want the column to have, and the row below that for the data you want to be displayed, using the value property to select the name of a field in the Dataset that has been assigned to the table. Thanks!